# Accessing parent instance data from child instances in .NET 5.0 / C# 9.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-5, c#-9.0

I have a .NET 5.0 web application that instantiates classes for each of the endpoints. Those classes instantiate child classes. Is there a more elegant or efficient way to access parent instance data from child instances besides the way I'm doing it right now?

As an example:

```
public class ComponentClass
{
    private PageClass _page;

    public ComponentClass(PageClass page)
    {
        _page = page;
    }

    public void ComponentMethod()
    {
        // Call the method from the parent instance
        page.PageMethod();
    }
}

public class PageClass
{
    private ComponentClass _component;

    public PageClass()
    {
        _component = new ComponentClass(this);
    }

    public async Task ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
         // Call the component's method
         _component.ComponentMethod();
    }

    public void PageMethod()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Specifically, I'm trying to avoid having to pass `this` to every ComponentClass instance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call a method on the parent, then you have two options. The first is to pass a reference of the parent into the child. There's no way around this, an object has no way to know in which object it is referenced from. In fact, it could be referenced by multiple parent objects.

The better solution is to use events. That way the child never knows anything about the parent(s) and can emit events that any number of components can subscribe to. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/) for more details on events. For example, your component could look something like this:

```
public class Component
{
    public event EventHandler Tick;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        EventHandler handler = Tick;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

And your PageClass:

```
public class PageClass
{
    public Component _component { get; set; }
    
    public void Init()
    {
        _component = new Component();
        _component.Tick += Component_Tick;
    }
    
    public void MakeComponentTick()
    {
        // This method is just for testing, it's likely this would be triggered by user input
        _component.DoSomething();
    }
    
    private void Component_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Component ticked!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think events are going to work in this scenario. The page has an internal StringBuilder which collects the rendered output of all the components when the page renders (not to mention that the component checks various variables on the page). Looks like I'm resigned to having to pass the reference back to the page when the component is created.

Comment: In that case, I'd rather still use events and pass in some kind of state manager object that is shared between all objects. Otherwise you have all sorts of cross concerns and SOLID violations. The Component should never know about the parent.